# Using Javascript node.js how do I parallel process For loops?

Tags: javascript, node.js, parallel-processing

I only started to learn javascript 2 days ago so I'm pretty new. I've written code which is optimal but takes 20 minutes to run. I was wondering if there's a simple way to parallel process with for loops e.g.

for (x=0; x<5; x++){ 
processor 1 do ...

for (x=5; x<10; x++){
processor 2 do ...

Comment: Javascript is strictly single-threaded.  If you have compute-bound work, you should use a different language.

Answer (score 5):

Since the OP wants to process the loop in parallel, the [`async.each()`](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#each) function from the [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) library is the ideal way to go.

I've had faster execution times using `async.each` compared to `forEach` in *nodejs*.

Answer (score 2):

web workers can run your code in parallel, but without sharing memory/variables etc - basically you pass input parameters to the worker, it works and gives you back the result.

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/workers/basics/

You can find nodejs implementations of this, example

https://www.npmjs.com/package/webworker-threads

OR, depending on how your code is written, if you're waiting on a lot of asynchronous functions, you can always rewrite your code to run faster (eg using event queuess instead of for loops - just beware of dependencies, order of execution, etc)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at the [async.js project](https://github.com/caolan/async), especially the [parallel](https://github.com/caolan/async#parallel) function.

Important quote about it :

> parallel is about kicking-off I/O tasks in parallel, not about parallel execution of code. **If your tasks do not use any timers or perform any I/O, they will actually be executed in series**. Any synchronous setup sections for each task will happen one after the other. **JavaScript remains single-threaded**.

Example :

```
async.parallel([
    function(callback){
        setTimeout(function(){
            callback(null, 'one');
        }, 200);
    },
    function(callback){
        setTimeout(function(){
            callback(null, 'two');
        }, 100);
    }
],
// optional callback
function(err, results){
    // the results array will equal ['one','two'] even though
    // the second function had a shorter timeout.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> To run code in parallel or want to make requests in parallel you can
> use Promise.all or Promise.settled.

Make all the queries in parallel (asynchronously). Resulting in each query firing at the same time.

```
let promise1 = new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(() => resolve('any-value'), 3000);
let responses = await Promise.all([promise1, promise2, promise3, ...])
for(let response of responses) {
  // format responses
  
  // respond to client
}
```

For more examples check out this [article](https://medium.com/serverlessguru/executing-code-in-parallel-javascript-a93740190c86)

Comment: Promise.all does not cause any parallelization. It makes the promises run concurrently, which is different from parallelization. This enables waiting for a bunch of promises all at once, which is more comfortable for the developer, but it does not affect performance.